# Early 90s or late 80s cartoon - gundam style fighter mech with "X" on body

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I know it's not a lot to go on, but I remember my parents having 1 VHS on an American voiced cartoon that featured a giant Gundam-style robot that had a big yellow "X" on black plate either on his chest or shoulder plates (or possibly both). It wasn't a very complicated looking mech either

Due to the extremely foggy memory of a time when I was so young I can't be 100% sure of exact details but I'm almost sure their base was in a mountain or something. Also played the Axel F Beverly cops song when he jumped in and the robot was flying out if I remember correctly.

This could be a very small-time cartoon that wasn't very well known as I've been searching over the Internet for a while and never seen a description or screenshot that matches but I'm hoping an enthusiast may come across this that knows what my brain is trying to piece together!

Don't restrict suggestions too close to my description... I do remember the "X" was there, but my memory may be playing tricks with me on other details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could this be [*"GoShogun"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GoShogun) (*"Sengoku Majin GōShōgun"*)? It is also known as *"Macron 1"*, *"Fulgutor"* and *"Gotriniton"* in some localized (and sometimes heavily edited) versions.

[image: The robot Goshogun and the three vehicles used by its three pilots]

The series originally aired in Japan in 1981, with a compilation movie released in 1982 and a sequel movie in 1985.
The American localization distributed by Saban with the name *"Macron 1"* integrated scenes from a different series and was released in 1986, so it fits the time frame you mention.

And, of course, there is the yellow-on-black X on the robot's chest.

**Maybe-matching detail:** in the American version, the music playing when the three pilots launch their vehicles sounds somewhat similar to the *Beverly Hills Cop* main theme:

**Non-matching detail:** from a quick search, the base of the good guys seems to be similar to a spaceship teleporting from place to place, rathern than a building in the mountains.

---

<sub>I have no first-hand memories of this series, but I watched a list of robotic series on an [Italian blog](https://docmanhattan.blogspot.com/2014/01/Robot-giapponesi-1981-1983.html)* and this was the only one matching the "yellow-on-black X" detail.

[*] which I'm not the author of or have any affiliation with, apart from reading it habitually</sub>

Comment: That's it! That's the one! Thank you so much! Yeah I think I mis-remembered the mountain base but after a bit of searching I found another comment on a YouTube video saying they added a couple of covers to the "getting ready" scenes including Beat It and Axel F, maybe more but the only episodes I had must have contained that one. Thank you so much for your help you're a legend!